# Hide all scale labels in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a graph that looked pretty decent.

It only showed one line, one dataset, and no label/y axis.

it was configured like this

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
            display: false
        },
        x: {
            display: false
        }
    }
}
```

but then I decided to add another dataset with a different scale.
So now my config looks like this:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    },
    scales: {
        y: [
            {
                id: 'viewTime',
                display: false
            },
            {
                id: 'diff',
                display: false
            }
        ],
        x: {
            display: false
        }
    }
}
```

And the issue is that is is in fact displaying both the `viewTime` *and* the `diff` scale.

Am I missing something or how do I hide all scales?

[image: graph scales]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scales are not array's anymore. In v3 every scale is its own object where the key is the scale ID so you will get this:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        yAxisID: 'y2'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        display: false
      },
      y2: {
        display: false
      },
      x: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```