# How to remove scale labels in chartjs from radar chart?

Tags: chart.js

I need to remove numbers from scale.

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815037/hide-all-scale-labels-in-chartjs" didn't help.

Setting `scale.display: false` or `scale.ticks.display: false` also don't change anything.

I'm using chartjs v4.3.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting chart object with `console.log(new Chart(ctx, config)` I found where `ticks` configuration is now:

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {r: {ticks: {display: false}}}  // <
  },
});
```